# Interact (sending data) between android application and tizen application

Tags: android, tizen

I want to send some data from application on my mobile (samsung S3 android kitkat) to an application on ( gear 2 neo  tizen) 
like here 
   I have a data like this on an andriod appliction
                                      {'id' = 1 , 'name' = 'mohamed' ,
                                       'id' = 2  , 'name' = 'ali'};
   I want to send it to tizen application on my smart watch
   any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create two applications, one for the smart watch and another for you phone. Later you can use the SAP protocol to exchange data (passing messages in form of strings). 
This is quite complex, but there is a nice tutorial inside Tizen SDK for Wearable.